# Reshaping Dataframe with multiple column and row headings, and duplicate column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

A question on Python Pandas DataFrame reshaping:

I currently have data in the following structure:

[image: Data Input]

I'd like to transform it into the following structure:

[image: Intended Output]

Can someone assist in accomplishing this?

I'm struggling with pretty much every step between point A and B. A simple transpose (i.e., "df.T") doesn't do the job given the multiple headings, and the dates which are oddly placed in the data structure without a label. Pandas also doesn't like the fact there are multiple "columns" with the same name, so it will only take part of the dataset. The intended output, as you can see from the image, is flattened, then sorted by Client, Product, and then Date. I've experimented with pivots, re-indexing, axes adjustments with no luck (likely b/c I suck).

This sample data should help recreate the Data Input image I've attached:

```
d = {'Client': ['','client1','client2', 'client2'], 
     'ProductType': ['','Tools','Tools', 'Tools'],
     'Product': ['','Hammer', 'Hammer','Drill'],
     'Qty': ['1/1/2022','200', '250','100'],
     'Margin': ['1/1/2022','2', '2.50','1'],
     'Price': ['1/1/2022','21', '26','11'],
     'Qty': ['1/2/2022','205', '259','119'],
     'Margin': ['1/2/2022','2', '2.50','1'],
     'Price': ['1/2/2022','21', '26','11']}
```

Would someone be able to assist?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the desired result if the date is a column of the original frame. It is sufficient to put it in the index when creating the pivot_table

```
dp = df.pivot_table(index=['Date', 'client'...etc], ...)
```